# Attendance Module PHP

Tags: php, forms, post, radio-button, submit

I am desingning an attendance module in php. To mark attendance using radio buttons in php i am using forms and posting it to other webpage.

Form Code:-

```
    <form method="POST" action="marked.php">
  <p align="center">
<center><h2>Your Subject Students</h2></center>
    <?php 
     $link=mysql_connect("mysql4.000webhost.com","a2101142_jxpolre","jxplor1") or die("Cannot Connect to the database!");
         mysql_select_db("a2101142_login",$link) or die ("Cannot select the database!");
     $query="SELECT sid,sname FROM studentdetails s,facultydetails f WHERE ( s.sub1=f.subid OR s.sub2=f.subid OR s.sub3=f.subid) AND f.fid=$id";
        $resource=mysql_query($query,$link);
          echo "<table align=\"center\" border=\"0\" width=\"70%\">
        <tr><td><b>S.No.</b></td> <td><b>Student ID</b></td> <td><b>Name</b></td> <td><b>Present</b></td>  <td><b>Absent</b></td></tr>  ";
$x=0;
while($result=mysql_fetch_array($resource))
    { $x++;
    echo "<tr><td>".$x."</td><td>".$result[0]."</td><td>".$result[1]."</td><td><input type='radio' name='attend[$result[0]]' value='Present'></td><td><input type='radio' name='attend[$result[0]]' value='Absent'></td></tr>";

    } echo "</table>";
          ?>
<center><input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Submit'>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<input type="reset" value="Reset"/></center>
</form>
```

Marked.php code:-

```
<?php


print_r($_POST);

?>
```

Here i'm receving output:-
Array ( [attend] => Array ( [2202] => Present [2203] => Present [2204] => Present [2208] => Present [2210] => Present [2211] => Present [2216] => Present [2217] => Present [2218] => Present ) [Submit] => Submit )

How to seperate $id and Present/Absent from $_POST()??
Please Help????/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `foreach` to achieve that.

```
foreach($_POST['attend'] as $id => $staus){
  echo $id; //will print 2202
  echo $status; // will print Present 
}
```

Hope this helps :)